# CanCan and ability block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I have this piece of code that defines CanCan's user permissions, but I don't understand what the conditions inside the block are for ?

```
    class Ability
          include CanCan::Ability

          def initialize(user)

            user.permissions.each do |permission|
              can permission.action.to_sym,
              permission.thing_type.constantize do |thing|
               thing.nil? || permission.thing_id.nil? || permission.thing_id == thing.id
              end
            end


end
end
```

So, this lines of code are bugging me:

```
permission.thing_type.constantize do |thing|
       thing.nil? || permission.thing_id.nil? || permission.thing_id == thing.id
end
```

I understand that block is used to define complex conditions and I guess that  `permission.thing_id == thing.id` is there so that permission is granted only for selected objects but I don't see the purpoose of  `thing.nil? || permission.thing_id.nil?`.What's that for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, [according to the CanCan docs](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks), when you pass a block to `can` (which is what's going on here), the permission is given only if the block returns true. The object passed in to the block is the object that the user might have permission to do something to.

What this does, then, is give the user permission to perform `permission.action` on the class `permission.thing_type` if:

1. `thing` is nil. This might happen in the case of things like `create` permission, which doesn't take a specific object (it takes the class instead).
2. `permission.thing_id` is nil. This is dealing with the case where the `Permission` object doesn't point at a specific thing. This feels like the opposite side of item 1. It might apply in the case of 'blanket' permissions - a permission that says a particular user can perform this action on *any* object of this class. OR
3. The `thing` has the id specified in the permission object.

Moral: Comment your code. Even if it's obvious to you right now what something does, it might not be to the next person. Who might also be you, in a few months.